# Custom PHP function for Login page to secure database

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I have written this function for my login inputs to make it safe:

```
function secureLogin($ary = array()){
      try{
          $securedArray = array();
          foreach($ary as $val){
            $val = str_replace("'","",$val);
            //$val = str_replace("%","",$val);
            $val = str_replace("drop ","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("show ","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("insert ","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("create ","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("update ","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("select ","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace("or ","",strtolower($val));
            $val = str_replace('"',"",$val);
            $val = str_replace(";","",$val);
            $securedArray[] = strip_tags($val);
            }
        }catch(Exception $exc){
                return $exc->getMessage();
                }
             return $securedArray;
        }
```

I have tested it with some tools like SQLMAP, Havij, and Acunetix tools which shows good results but i want to get some experts suggestions to make my login page / inputs from login page as much as secure it should be.

Comment: i think prepared statement or pdo is enough

Comment: ya but i have seen some hackers are still able to bypass pdo security with second level attacks...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are you trying to catch in your code, all those str_replace will not raise any PDOException.

If you use correctly prepared statements you don't need to replace any word. Also just deleting important word such these will not making you login secure, will only need harder for an attacker to exploit it.